# How do I rotate A2212 2200Kv BLDC via 220 V Ac?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, ac-dc

I use Lipo battery (11.1V 25 C 3s) to rotate the motor. But now I want to rotate motor via 220V AC (Home supply).I followed [this tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/AC-to-DC-Conversion/) and successfully converted 220V AC to 12 V DC. But I am not able to rotate the motor.

I was using [this motor.](https://www.electronicscomp.com/a2212-2200kv-bldc-brushless-motor-india),[this battery with the capacity of 3300 mAH](https://shop.robosynckits.in/product/shangyi-3s-lipo-battery-11-1v/) and [this ESC.](https://robu.in/product/standard-30a-bldc-esc-electronic-speed-controller/). To test the circuit I am using [this servotester](https://robu.in/product/digital-multi-servo-tester-esc-rc-consistency-ccpm-master-speed-control/)

I would be highly obliged I am corrected.

Thanking you.

Comment: For anyone to answer this they would need part numbers and datasheet links for the BLDC, the BLDC driver and schematics for the battery configuration and the mains configuration. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: [Your motor](http://www.bhabbott.net.nz/A2212-6.html) draws more than 2.3 amps with no load at 12V, but your power supply can only deliver ~1A at best. You need a power supply rated for at least 20A to make full use of this motor.

Comment: @BruceAbbott please tell me how shall I make a power supply of 20 A.

Comment: You need a transformer and bridge rectifier rated for at least 20A. Then use a circuit like this:- https://www.circuitlib.com/index.php/schematics/product/24-20a-adjustable-power-supply/category_pathway-26. Or if you have access to PC parts, just use an ATX-12V power supply rated for >=20A.